# Get Key value of a hash in sort order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

Here is my code

```
{"wow"=>["wow"], "you"=>["you", "you"], "are"=>["are"], "a"=>["a"], "good"=>["good"], "guy"=>["guy"], "but"=>["but"], "sometime"=>["sometime"], "take"=>["take"], "very"=>["very"], "wrong"=>["wrong"], "decision"=>["decision"]}
```

i want to get result

```
{"you"=>2, "are"=>1, "a"=>1, "good"=>1, "guy"=>1, "but"=>1, "sometime"=>1, "take"=>1, "very"=>1, "wrong"=>1, "decision"=>1,"wow" =>1}
```

how can i do this please help me

Comment: Ravendra, this site is not for "write the code for me". It's for "I want to do this, I am doing it this way. I am expecting this output because of this and that, but I'm getting this. Can you point out what the problem is?" If you don't want to spend time solving your problem, why should we?

Comment: ok sir for next time i will try to solve problem

Comment: I think you should do it this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
old_hash = {"wow"=>["wow"], "you"=>["you", "you"], "are"=>["are"], "a"=>["a"], "good"=>["good"], "guy"=>["guy"], "but"=>["but"], "sometime"=>["sometime"], "take"=>["take"], "very"=>["very"], "wrong"=>["wrong"], "decision"=>["decision"]}

new_hash = Hash.new
old_hash.each {|k,v| new_hash.merge!(k=>v.size) }
```